# Convert bytes array to human readable string and vice versa in .NET

Tags: .net, string, base64, arrays, bitconverter

Since using [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.convert.tobase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) & [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) could lead to Out of Memory Exception, when very large string is input.

Is there another alternative ways to convert a bytes array to human readable string and vice versa in .NET?

Comment: If you base64 encode/decode strings/byte arrays so large that OOM is a risk, ur doing it rong. Encode/decode streams instead (that's what you probably start with anyway, a stream).

Comment: @AntonTykhyy: I've known it's better to encode/decode stream instead of string. But in my case, I have to extract string from message (inner xml from SOAP message), encrypt it and push back to message. So I don't have stream in my hand now, so I'm going to find another alternative way, not Convert.From/ToBase64String.

Comment: So what size byte arrays do you have to deal with? Also, you might want to post some code.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy: I've asked another question about OOM exception when using `Convert.From/ToBase64String` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227757/net-convert-to-frombase64string-cause-outofmemory-exception-in-soap-message)
Please have a look at my attached code. Thanks!